# How do we initialize a Magicblock session token account

Tags: magicblock, session-token

Do I have to create an initialize instruction for the session token or is there a way that this is taken care of automatically?

I was looking at the [lumberjack example](https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-examples/tree/main/lumberjack) and I couldn't find an instruction that `init`s the session token account.

Comment: I'm not sure how common Magic Block usage might be in the ecosystem, so it might be easier to ask directly on their GitHub

Comment: are there any alternatives to a session token program in Solana?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry!